# Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid real-valued random variables. Show $P[|X-Y| \le 2] \le 3P[|X-Y| \le 1]$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

Found this question in The Probabilistic Method and tried for hours to prove it, but I'm not getting anywhere. Can anyone walk me through it? I see that if we can show $P[1 \le X - Y \le 2] \le P[|X -Y| \le 1]$ the claim will follow. This is intuitively appealing but I don't see how to proceed.

Comment: Here is a thought, but not sure how to finish it. $$\mathbb{P}[|X-Y| \le a] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty [F(y+a) - F(y-a)] f(y) dy$$ so in your case it suffices to prove that $$F(y+2) - F(y-2) \le 3 F(y+1) - 3F(y-1), \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$$ but I am not sure how to prove this is in general.

Comment: See here for one way to prove this claim: http://web.mit.edu/cuenca/Public/alonspencersection1.pdf